# Validate in excel before uploading to access

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to upload an Excel document into Access. I have used VBA to unhide all columns and rows and then delete columns and rows that are not being used. All of the worksheets upload into Access properly except one. This particular worksheet attempts to upload a field and label it Field 12. I am unable to find a way to delete this field. Any help?

Comment: right, but what is it *in Excel*?  A column?  Check the sheet's used range. Often there is an "extra" column or row. If that's the case, then delete the entire column, save the file, and try again

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the first column after your data...

Try either in VBA or in Excel deleting the columns to the right of your data (not just contents but an actual delete). I've found this typically happens when the columns to the right of your data contained data at one point and Access / Excel sees those as still containing data. Then try your import again.

Alternatively, you could upload into a new Access staging table before pulling your desired known columns into the final table through an INSERT query. Then you can delete the staging table if you like or delete it before the next import. In this way, each import can have its own "added columns".